# Can I control which App Engine instance the cron job accesses

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I have an App Engine server with two instances - the first is the main, active instance and the second is a test instance. This setup allows me to test features on existing datastore entries without screwing up the active server too much.

I'm trying to set up a cron job for a new servlet endpoint that I added on instance 2, but the cron job tries to access the default endpoint (which doesn't exist), and specifying the full url to the second instance is not allowed. Here's what I tried (3 variations):

```
<cronentries>
  <cron>

   1. <url>2-dot-my-app.appspot.com/ping</url> // doesn't work
   2. <url>/ping</url>                         // this tries to access the default instance
   3. <url>/ping</url>                         // tried this long-shot as well, obviously didn't work
      <target>v3</target>

    <schedule>every 2 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```

Does anybody have suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was more straightforward than I thought:

```
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/ping</url>
    <target>3</target>
    <schedule>every 2 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>
</cronentries>
```